# How to make the SelectedItem in Combobox(customize DataTemplate) shows only specific property of the item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a `ComboBox` that shows a list of information:

- `NameOfEstablishment`
- `BIN`
- `Owner`
- `BusinessAddress`

...appearing like so:

[image]

Code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="BploList" 
          Text="{Binding Search}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SearchSelected}"
          Grid.Row="0"
          Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
          FontSize="16" 
          materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Search"
          Margin="5 5 65 5" 
          IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameOfEstablishment}" FontSize="12" Foreground="#D8AC6A"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="250" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BIN}" FontSize="11" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="250" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Owner}" FontSize="11" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="250" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding BusinessAddress}" FontSize="11" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="250" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

### Problem

`SelectedItem` should show the `NameOfEstablishment` value ***only*** but it instead shows as the **full object**:

[image]

As for Source of ComboBox

```
private BindingList<BPLOSearchModel> _bploList;

        public BindingList<BPLOSearchModel> BploList
        {
            get { return _bploList; }
            set 
            {
                _bploList = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BploList);
            }
        }
```

Properties of BPLOSearchModel

```
public class BPLOSearchModel
    {
        public string BIN { get; set; }
        public string NameOfEstablishment { get; set; }
        public string BusinessAddress { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
    }
```

As for SearchSelected

```
    private string _searchSelected;

    public string SearchSelected
    {
        get { return _searchSelected; }
        set 
        {
            _searchSelected = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SearchSelected);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @MickyD ok, already Edited.

Comment: Thank-you for edit

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [SelectedValuePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath?view=net-5.0) is for. It is used to

> get or set the path that is used to get the SelectedValue of the SelectedItem

In your case, set it like

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedValuePath="NameOfEstablishment" ... />
```

Note that there is also a nice [How to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-use-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath-and-selecteditem?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) at Microsoft.